# Kafka metrics don't appear to be updating correctly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

### The problem

I'm monitoring the Kafka offset lag using the metrics output from Spring's Actuator Prometheus endpoint. I've noticed in some instances when doing a large backfill job that some of my nodes (6 instances of the app) will stop updating the metric until all messages have been consumed. The nodes in question are still processing the messages correctly (as evidenced by logging and the end results). When graphing my metrics, this appears as a flat line in the offset lag until the very end, when they lines drop off a cliff edge.

It's also worth noting that on occasions where metrics are being updated as expected and we've performed an app-deployment, we may then seen the metrics go from acting as expected, to one or more of the nodes flat-lining, as described above.

It feels to me like some kind of non-deterministic race condition, possibly explained by the way I've configured my app?

[image: 1]

### Context

I have an application that consumes from several topics. All but one of the topics has a shared message format, and only one of the topics has a different format as it's a "retry" topic, so the message is different. I also wanted to apply a filter only to the regular topics, so to facilitate this, I create two separate `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` beans, example:

```java
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, MessageA> messageAContainerFactory(
        ConsumerFactory<Long, MessageA> consumerFactory) { ... }

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, MessageB> messageBContainerFactory(
        ConsumerFactory<Long, MessageB> consumerFactory) { ... }
```

And then I reference those beans in the relevant `@KafkaListener` annotations:

```java
@KafkaListener(
        topics = "message-a-topic",
        containerFactory = "messageAContainerFactory")
public void consumeMessageA(MessageA messageA) { ... }

@KafkaListener(
        topics = "message-B-topic",
        containerFactory = "messageBContainerFactory")
public void consumeMessageB(MessageB messageB) { ... }
```

Apart from these beans, there isn't much else in play. The application config for Kafka looks like so:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      max-poll-records: 10
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          deserializer:
            value:
              delegate:
                class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
          json:
            value:
              default:
                type: com.example.MessageA
```

---

I should stress that I haven't noticed any problem with the functionality - messages appear to be consumed and processed as expected. This only seems to affect the way metrics are updated.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Might this have something to do with the batch size that your consumers are reading from kafka?  I haven't looked into the consumer stats, but is it possible that the consumer reads a large batch of messages, but doesn't decrease the lag until that whole batch has been processed?

Comment: Our batch size is currently set very low (10 records) so I don't think that's the issue. We also have another similar application processing Kafka events which doesn't seem to have the same problem. The principal difference appears to be that this app has 2 separate consumer factories and multiple listeners.